# Notepad++/cmd output shows an error that IDLE does not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was calling for an image for a sprite (using notepad++) and the cmd output gave me an error.

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("invader.png").convert()
                                                      ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

After running the same code in IDLE it worked just fine with no error messages.

I saved and tested the code in notepad++ again and it ran without a problem. Is there a way to get notepad++ stop giving me error messages that aren't errors? both IDLE and notepad++ are up to date and I'm using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with indentation in your code. So, you should try erasing the whole line and typing it again. Crude, maybe, but it always works for me.

Let me know if this works.